# How to use the Firebase Auth REST API to create users in an Emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When reading the firebase emulator documentation, I saw that it [mentioned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#non-interactive_testing) a REST [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) that would expose endpoints to create users. I have found the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) to create users but they don't seem to be for the emulator.

I've tried using the sample requests for signup but with the auth emulator domain (`localhost:9099`). I've tried copying the example requests specifically for the auth emulator but changing it to mimic how the signup api looks like, none of this has worked however and they have just thrown 404s.

Does anyone have a sample request that can be made to create a user in the firebase emulator? Or is this something we need to create client code for?

Comment: You probably need to replace `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1` with `http://localhost:port`. So the signup URL should look like: `http://localhost:port/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks for responding! Yes I tried this, but it did not work.

Comment: And just for more info, this URL also gives a 404: `http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/accounts:signUp?key=${config.firebase.apiKey}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I followed the HTTP requests being made from the emulator web UI and this is what worked for me:

```js
await fetch(`http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=${config.firebase.apiKey}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'user@test.com',
    password: 'pass1234',
    returnSecureToken: true,
  }),
});
```

And for completeness sake, here's how I clear out the users:

```js
await fetch(`http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/projects/${config.firebase.projectId}/accounts`, {
  method: 'DELETE',
});
```

Comment: You're awesome thank you! One think to notice also is that you don't have to use an api key. I just put "fakeapikey" as the key and it all works the same.

Comment: I created a gist with this request as a fetch request and curl request [here](https://gist.github.com/joshpetit/4f24ad7b824753dca08d6f05ffcf5ddf). If anyone figures out firestore and the other REST APIs it'd be nice to add on there.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to set the new user with an predefined UID?

Comment: @João Melo, I would say your best bet would be to [export your data and restore it.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup). The API doesn't offer a way to specify the uuid assigned to a user.